# Dynamically display text then exit void

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple runner style game in unity, and have run into an issue: when the player "dies", the score and game over flash on the screen, alternating frames.

I am very new to C# and dont really know what else to try.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour{
        public PlayerMovement movement;
        private int lives = 0;
        public Transform player;
        public Text scoreText;
        public Rigidbody rb = null;
        private bool abort = false;
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle") {
            if (lives >= 3) {
                movement.enabled = false;
                Debug.Log("We Hit the thing");
                Debug.Log(movement);
                rb.AddForce(0, 0, 0);
                transform.position = new Vector3(0,1,-30);
                scoreText.text = "Level failed - Press C to try again";

                rb.AddForce(0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                lives = lives + 1;
            }
        }
    }

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (scoreText.text == "-30") {
            //DISPLAY TEXT AND LEAVE THE VOID FIXEDUPDATE()
            scoreText.text = "Level failed - Press C to try again";
            return;
        } else {
            //CONTINUE RUNNING THIS UNTILL -30 IS REACHED
            scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
        }
    }

void Update() {
    if ( Input.GetKey("c") ) {
        movement.enabled = true;
            transform.position = new Vector3(0,1,0);

            lives = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a github link
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackcrane/jackcrane.github.io/master/PlayerCollision.cs

Answer (score 0):

When the player is dead, `scoreText.text` will be set to "Level failed - Press C to try again", so the following code will be executed:

```
 else {
     //CONTINUE RUNNING THIS UNTILL -30 IS REACHED
     scoreText.text = player.position.z.ToString("0");
 }
```

Then `scoreText.text` will be changed to "-30"

So next fixed update frame will execute:

```
if (scoreText.text == "-30") {
    //DISPLAY TEXT AND LEAVE THE VOID FIXEDUPDATE()
    scoreText.text = "Level failed - Press C to try again";
    return;
}
```

Now the text has been changed back to "Level failed - Press C to try again", loops.

I don't know how to fix this, because the logic is in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Always try to score in PlayerPrefs which is an important feature of the unity to store score the count . In case you don't want to show the score or the count . just use the object of the text and set empty string to the text . Simple . The benefit for using PlayerPref is that it will store the final or end score of the player and then even you make string empty . Still the score will be stored separately. So Whenever you want that score value just use Playerpref.getInt("Score"); 
The score will be get in any variable and can be used further .

### Code for making string empty

```
if (scoreText.text == "-30") {
    //DISPLAY TEXT AND LEAVE THE VOID FIXEDUPDATE()
    scoreText.text = "";
    return;
}
```

### Code for PlaerPref:-

```
var myVariable : float;

PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Player Score", 10.0);

myVariable = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Player Score");

print (myVariable);
```

### Conclusion

The result can be get and set through the playerprefs function . It uses the keys concepts and store in files.